# How to discretize mixed partial derivatives?

Tags: numerical-methods, computational-mathematics, finite-differences

How to discretize $\frac{\partial^3 f}{\partial x\partial y^2}$ at mesh point $(i,j)$? 
We should use mesh points which are nearest to $(i,j)$.

Comment: I am looking for the discretized mixed partial derivatives by using the nearest point to $(x_i,y_j)$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In my questions, I have figured it out for numerical simulations. $\frac{\partial^3 u}{\partial x\partial y^2}=\frac{u_{i+1,j+1}-u_{i-1,j+1}+u_{i+1,j-1}-u_{i-1,j-1}-2(u_{i+1,j}-u_{i-1,j})}{2\delta x(\delta y)^2}$

Comment: Grr, I did not notice you had two derivatives in $y$. For fractions with multiple sup/superscripts, I suggest `\dfrac` or displayed formula...